# Value lookup on the fly in angular

Tags: angularjs

Got two sets of data. The first one is postits and the otherone is userlist. 
Each object in postits contains a set of values about a document, one of them being the owner, which is set to the internal id. 
The second set (userlist) contains the id of users and the name.

My problem is, I now want to print my list of postits, but I want to print the name of the owner rather than their id. Is this possible.

The below code works (except that postit.owner currently is the id):

```
<tr ng-repeat="postit in postits">
    <td>Control</td>
    <td><small>{{postit.type}}</small></td>
    <td><small>{{postit.owner }}</small></td>
    <td><small>{{postit.action.review | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</small></td>
    <td><small>{{postit.title}}</small></td>

</tr>
```

The user list information is also available in the following format:

```
[{"_id":"558869db610eb146a526728f","userName":"Bengt Bjorkberg"},{"_id":"55895508f35d9f020970ea91","userName":"test2"},{"_id":"5589550ff35d9f020970ea92","userName":"test3"}]
```

Both sets of data is available in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function (e.g. `getPostitOwner`) on the scope that accepts an `id` as its param and returns the owner. You'd use it like this:

```
<td><small>{{ postit.type }}</small></td>
<td><small>{{ getPostitOwner(postit.owner).userName }}</small></td>
```

As for the lookup function implementation:

```
$scope.getPostitOwner = function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
        if (userlist[i]._id === id) {
            return userlist[i];
        }
    };
}
```

Mind that this lookup function will run quite often. In this kind of situations I'd usually format the `postits` collection to add owners' objects to each `postit` just after I have both those lists instead.

Comment: Thought there might be an easier way, but to tell the truth, your solution was pretty good:)